# Why my Docker container's writable layer persists after the container exits?

Tags: docker, containers

Docker's [storage overview](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) documentation says:

> - **The data doesn’t persist when that container is no longer running**, and it can be difficult to get the data out of the container if another process needs it.
> - A container’s writable layer is tightly coupled to the host machine where the container is running. You can’t easily move the data somewhere else.
> - Writing into a container’s writable layer requires a storage driver to manage the filesystem. The storage driver provides a union filesystem, using the Linux kernel. This extra abstraction reduces performance as compared to using data volumes, which write directly to the host filesystem.

As you can see, the docs say, "The data doesn’t persist when that container is no longer running". So why isn't the data removed when I stop my container?

[image: Action logs]

Comment: When you stop a container, it still exists (including its file system).You can even restart it using `docker start`. Data is only lost when you remove the container and create a new one with `docker run`.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly  response, but why documents said “The data doesn’t persist when that container is no longer running”. In my opinion, "not running" means "Stoped"

Comment: @Bruce In the Docker way of thinking, the container are supposed to be removed once they are not of any use. That's why they might be a misunderstanding. So your system calling the run should remove  the containers (docker rm container_name) once they have done their purpose

Comment: The writable layer deleted when you run "docker rm <container-id>".

However, if you have started the container with "--rm" flag, stopping the container will immediately remove it and its writable layer. No need to explicitly run "docker rm" in this case.

"docker ps -a" will show you if container was stopped but has not been removed yet, so its writable layer still exists.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen and the comments confirm, the data does persist in a stopped container. You can restart the container and see the data in the container specific filesystem. You can also use `docker cp` to extract those files from the container. I have submitted the following [documentation PR](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/7706) to update the docs and remove any confusion (thank you for pointing out the wording).